# How to lock the X cursor in VNC?

Tags: vnc, minecraft, cursor

I have a Raspberry Pi 4B I've been running some graphical applications on it that lock the cursor (Minecraft, as an example). On the Pi (server), the cursor locks to the center of the window. But in the RealVNC VNC Viewer app on my phone (and on my desktop) the cursor doesn't lock. And when I move the cursor, I just go spinning in-game. Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance!

```
Mods:
Sodium
Altoclef
Baritone

Pi 4B:
4GB RAM (3.75 after VRAM allocate)
256MB VRAM
CPU @ 2.5 GHz
GPU @ 750 MHz
Experimental V3D driver enabled
```

Comment: This normally requires the input application to have a pref for MouseWarp [on/off]. It's a well-known issue for 3D gaming. For any particular game, you'd need to check their support structure or documentation. Games warp the mouse position back to centre at each mouse-down & allow drags that would ordinarily go beyond the screen bounds to continue. Disabling MouseWarp will stop the re-centring [& therefore spinning], but will also prevent drags from going outside the viewport.

Comment: @Tetsujin I turned off "Raw Input" in controls, and now it spins less and is a little more controllable. Albeit the cursor still can't warp back to the middle, or opposite side of the screen. This appears to be an issue with the VNC Viewer itself, but I'm not too certain.